# Copy a column value/field/row from a table to another table

Tags: mysql, count, phpmyadmin, group-by

i have a table named `data_table` which had a column name `status` and has a column value or field `pending` and `approved` i want to get the count or total of that 2 field to another table named `total_status` that had a column `total_pending` and `total_approved`

what's the best way to achieve that results? im using phpmyadmin btw to query

**data_table**
| column1 | column2 |    status   |
|   xxxx     |   xxxx     |  pending  |
|   xxxx     |   xxxx     | approved |
|   xxxx     |   xxxx     | approved |
|   xxxx     |   xxxx     |  pending  |
|   xxxx     |   xxxx     | approved |

[click to see table structure](https://i.gyazo.com/cf448cc2eec8063aa2d8877b5c3af832.png)

*i want the result will be like this below:*

**total_status**
| total_pending | total_approved |
|         2            |           3             |

[click to see table structure](https://i.gyazo.com/9a8f07d01982740e0248c4bd681ec3e8.png)

hope you got my point :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
  sum(case when status = 'pending' then 1 end) as total_pending,
  sum(case when status = 'approved ' then 1 end) as total_approved 
from data_table
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use a GROUP BY query like this:

```
SELECT status, count(*) as total
FROM data_table
GROUP BY status
```

if you really want to have two columns you can use two inline queries:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT count(*) FROM data_table WHERE status="Pending") AS total_pending,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM data_table WHERE status="Approved") AS total_approved
```

then you can create a new table with this syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE total_status
SELECT ...your select query above...
```